# Displaying a JSON in a table ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a JWT that I want to display its contents after signature validation. so, I verify the signature like this:

```
var verified = JWT.Decode(token, publicKey);
```

In this case, `verified` is a `string` containing the JSON payload, looks something like this:

```
{"sub":"211668914321303","aud":"MUSCA","ver":"1.0.0","nbf":1544459925,"iss":"blimp gmbh","rle":"MUSCA_ACCESS","prm":"This chunk is bound to the something for blimp gmbh","exp":4703150773,"iat":1544459925,"jti":"46"}
```

now to view this on a page in form of a table, it's easier to send it as a JSON, and loop on its Type and Value, like this:

```
var verifiedJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(verified); //convert to JSON
ViewBag.payload = verifiedJSON
```

in my view, I loop on the ViewBag like this

```
<table class="table-bordered table-responsive">
@foreach (var line in ViewBag.payload)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@line.Type</td>
        <td>@line.Value</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I would expect that the table will show type and value in columns, but instead of the type(key), I get the word Property, with the expected value in each row!

[image: faulty table]

I tried to display the JSON below the table to see if it came with "property" in the key fields, but it viewed with the correct key names. am I missing something or why can't I get the table to view the keys correctly?

Comment: You're doing `line.Type` (which of course will return Property... as it's basically the Type of the Key (in the key:value pair)). I'm not sure what's the correct one off the top of my head but it should be something like `line.Key` (As in the name of the key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue thanks to [jabberwocky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6677508/jabberwocky) 
I copied a table that was looping on an IEnumerable, and changed the variable which is a JSON, and by referring to [Json.NET Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm), I found out that the Key is not called `Key` or `Type`. It is called `Name`

Comment: Glad I could help dude. Cheers